# How do I give label to vSwitches on VMWare?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtualhost, virtual-machines, vswitch

I've searched extensively trying to name the vSwitches that I create, but all I can name them are "vSwitchX" where x= some number. How do I give these switches names? I'm using the Web Client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible using the UI.

On the CLI:

*Create a new Switch with a name:*

```
esxcli network vswitch standard add --vswitch-name=vSwitch
```

*Rename an existing switch:*

According to: http://www.cyberfella.co.uk/2012/04/11/rename-vswitch/

```
/etc/vmware/esc.conf

/net/vswitch/child[0001]/name = “vSwitch4“
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to rename your vSwitches. It is not a common practice (hence the omission from the GUI and the difficulty you're having).

This is mainly because the actual Portgroup names are what matter from a VM and clarity perspective. See below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the reason we give hostnames to Cisco Switches? We can also add a description to each of the interfaces, right? -.-

I have many vSwitches. I would like to group the Portgroups together on one Switch and name it, so it becomes much easier to navigate than break my head on which vSwitch did I keep that port group. Moreover, if you have about 10 vSwitches and you delete some in the middle, the continuity in the naming is broken.

Comment: @AbhishekSha But it's really not the right way to do this... It's not common to have lots of vSwitches either :(

Comment: @AbhishekSha I agree, I'd bet there's something you can change in your architecture to make things much more manageable without naming the vSwitches; if you need those, then something's probably wrong.